# The opposite of "rights" — "obligations" or "responsibilities"?

Tags: antonyms

Lead SA composed a [Bill of Responsibilities](http://www.pod945.co.za/podcast/other/BOR/files/Call%20to%20Action.pdf) to complement the South African Bill of Rights and express those rights in a practical way.

I think it is an inspirational idea, but I expected the corollary of rights to be *obligations* rather than *responsibilities*.

Is there a difference between my *responsibilities* and my *obligations*, and which term is the most accurate and appropriate in this context?

Comment: I think this can turn into quite a philosophical discussion. In my opinion "responsibilities" is more fitting here, because of the way  "rights" is used. In another context "obligation" can be the better match.

Comment: Responsibilities, duties, and obligations are sufficiently [synonymous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/duties?s=b) that any one of them can be used, probably interchangeably, unless the context clearly demands one word rather than the other two. They can all be stipulated as equivalent for the purpose of the document in question, but I think that's unnecessary. There need be no semantic or "philosophical" discussion about the meanings of these three words: they are basic enough for any semi-educated native Anglophone to understand what they mean when contrasted with "rights".

Comment: Though interchangeable, _responsibilities_ and _obligations_ can have different psycological effects on some people. To some, the former is more easily digested than the latter. When addressing masses it could be something to consider.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bill of Responsibilities](http://www.pod945.co.za/podcast/other/BOR/files/Call%20to%20Action.pdf) referred to in the question appears to be a list of moral obligations, duties, or responsibilities that  responsible citizens of South Africa will undertake.  In this case, one could substitute *obligations* for *responsibilities*, but as suggested below, *responsibilities* serves better.

Briefly, the relevant meanings are:
• *[responsibility](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/responsibility#Noun)*: “A duty, obligation or liability for which someone is held accountable”
• *[duty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duty#Noun)*: “That which one is morally or legally obligated to do”
• *[obligation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obligation#Noun)*: “A social, legal, or moral requirement, duty, contract, or promise that compels someone to follow or avoid a particular course of action”, or “(law) A legal agreement stipulating a specified payment or action...”

Except in contracts, job descriptions, etc., responsibilities are thought of as moral obligations rather than legal obligations.  If the qualifier *moral* is intended but not stated, the word *responsibilities* is more likely to be used than is *obligations*; and if the qualifier *legal* is intended but not stated, vice versa.

In short, *obligation* has an additional commonly-used legal sense that often is not carried by *responsibility* or *duty*.

Comment: Also, "Rights and Responsibilities" is a common, alliterative phrase to cover both sides of a relationship.